# Cannot access property via dot notation javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {a:1,b:2};
var str = "a";

console.log(obj.str);
```

This outputs `undefined`. What am i missing here ?

Comment: `obj[str]`, `.str` will try to get a property named `str` and not a property named by the string stored in `str`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use []

```
var obj = {a:1,b:2};
var str = "a";

console.log(obj[str]);
```